# Python opening images without cmd

Tags: python, image, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am working on a project which includes opening images through a `tkinter` window using `Pillow` module.

Whenever I try to open images, they are opened with a black screen on their back.

How can I open them alone?

I click on a photo here: 
[image: first photo]

and it opens with a black screen behind:
[image: second photo]

This is my **go_to_function**:

```
from PIL import Image

def go_to_photo():
    try:
        img = Image.open(source_file_org_images_path + "/" + photo_name_name + '.png')
        img.show()
        img.close()
    except:
        try:
            img = Image.open(source_file_org_images_path + "/" + photo_name_name + '.jpg')
            img.show()
            img.close()
        except:
            try:
                img = Image.open(source_file_org_images_path + "/" + photo_name_name + '.jpeg')
                img.show()
                img.close()
            except:
                print('without a photo')
```

Comment: how do you run this function ? Directly in code or using `subprocess()` ? Probably `img.show()`  creating window runs `cmd.exe`(this black screen behide). Maybe use `tk.TopLevel()` to create own window and display image in `tk.Label`.

Comment: I am using it directly in code. Yes, img.show() creates the windows and I don't know how to close it. Thanks for the idea but isn't there any built-in arguments of Image which blocks the black screen.

Comment: I don't think that there is any arguments. As I know `show()` was created to display image in short script - mostly to debug code.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.Image.show):

> On Windows, it saves the image to a temporary BMP file, and uses the
>   standard BMP display utility to show it.

This means that you can simply change your default program to open bmp files with to e.g. Paint, and it will use that program to display your images.

By the way: you can move the `img.show()` and `img.close()` to after your try-except blocks, so you don't have to repeat yourself so often.

Comment: It didn't work. I use Picasa as default program but it is of no use.